# Unique (Filter) Values Not Copying on Summary Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to copy data tables from several sheets. I noticed that I am missing a column on the "Summary" sheet. This column is developed on the other sheets using a unique filter =UNIQUE(FILTER(L:L,L:L<>"")). The ActiveSheet.Paste function works to copy unique filters, but I cannot get it to work with my code. Any advice?

```
Sub Summary()

Dim wkstDst As Worksheet
Dim wkstSrc As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range

LastRow = Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row

Set wkstDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
wkstDst.Select

Range("A9", Cells(LastRow, "F")).ClearContents

For Each wkstSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If wkstSrc.Name <> "Summary" Then
        With wkstSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(11, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 5)
            With rngSrc
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                    Destination:=wkstDst.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
                .AutoFilter
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next wkstSrc
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works even if the data in a particular column is the result of the `UNIQUE` function. Your problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering what adjustment I need to make to copy the "unique" column.

Comment: I'm wondering also. Given the lack of detail about your data, I cannot advise you further. It might help you to read the Help topic for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then **EDIT** your question to provide relevant information.